# Solving for $x$: $x^x=N$

Tags: algorithms

In a case such as $x^x=27$ we can solve by inspection that $x=3$.

But how can we solve this algorithmically in general, given that $N\in Q$ where $Q\subset\Bbb Z$ and $Q=[1,10^{10}]$ and $x\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: My first instinct will be to take $\log$ both sides.

Comment: Using Taylor's approximation of $x \ln x$ might help.

Comment: If you like some exploring of this, you might have fun reading the article "wexzal" (written in the 90'ies I think) and possibly only accessible via archive.org. When I read it first, it made me really curious. *(If you've difficulties to find it online, I've an early copy of it)* P.s. another nice treatize on this subject is the "x^x-spindle" which analyzes the behave of the function using a graphical representation.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms. Could I get a copy of it ? My e-mail address is in my profile. Thanks.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I want to learn more about it, can I get a copy of the paper, please? My e-mail address is in my profile,too. Thanks.

Comment: @zoosuck: didn't find your email adress. But I've put it on my website some time ago. See http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/WexZal.pdf (It was a pure ascii-file, so it is not formatted)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find $x$, you have to solve the equation

$$x\ln(x) = \ln(N)$$

This equation does not have a closed form solution using only the functions we usually use. However, using [Lambert's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is the inverse of the function $$x\mapsto x\ln x,$$ you can still express the solution exactly, since $W(\ln N) = W(x\ln x)=x$

Answer (score 2):

Newton's method has the fastest convergence that I know of.

For solving 0 = f(x)

The idea is to

1.) guess a solution $x_0$

2.) put it into the function you want to find the zero solution of (ie: calculate $f(x_0)$ )

3.) calculate the derivative at that point $f'(x_0)$

4.) Use this information to find the equation of a straight line with slope $f'(x_0)$ and passing through $f(x_0)$

5.) find where this line hits zero

6.) use this as your next guess for x

Which ends up being 
$x_0 - (f(x_0)/f'(x_0))$

Repeat this over and over.

So you end up iterating

$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

in our case $f(x) = x^x -27$

since we want to know when this is zero

or

f(x) = x^x - c

if you prefer

See [here](http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/Differentiation/first_derivative.html) for finding the derivative of $x^x$

So the final iteration scheme will be

$x_{n+1} = x_n -[\frac{{x_n}^{x_n} - C}{ln(x_n + 1){x_n}^{x_n}}]$

Comment: check out http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^x 
you can see that on the domain x >= 1,  x^x is a monotonically increasing function. This is ideal for using newton's method. The interesting stuff happens when x < 0, then imaginary numbers get involved ... but perhaps that's another story

Comment: The Lambert's function is a really interesting idea, computing a result from it boils down to newton's method as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation