# Without using a calculator how to solve $x^x = 100$?

Tags: mental-arithmetic

Without using a calculator how to solve $x^x = 100$ ?
A way of finding an approximation to 2 decimals would be good neough.

I know about the Lmabert W function but one cannot compute it mentally. This is why I believe my question not to be a duplicate.

Comment: i think that is impossible

Comment: Sorry, but how would you do that **with using** a calculator? Then, you do the same with mental arithmetic.

Comment: See here: [How to solve $x^x=100$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087365/how-to-solve-xx-100) or [Solving for $x$: $x^x=N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168862/solving-for-x-xx-n) or [How do you solve this equations where the unknown is to the power of the unknown?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487603/how-do-you-solve-this-equations-where-the-unknown-is-to-the-power-of-the-unknown)

Comment: You need something called the "Lambert W function" for a closed form, but it numerical methods can be applied to get estimates.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I do not think it is a duplicate, because this question explicitely prohibits using calculators.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2

Comment: @M.Winter, I agree the prohibition on calculators gives the question some novelty, but in that case it'd help for the OP to specify what it means to "solve" the equation.

Comment: I meant finding an approximate answer at 2 decimals. For the lambert W function, we cannot compute mentally taht is why it is a different from the one you pointed out.

Comment: @Arthurim Maybe you could ask how to approximate Lambert $W$ without a calculator instead? Wikipedia has quite some information, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $\log2\approx0.3$ and $\log3\approx0.48$ (where "$\log$" is log base $10$), then you can show that

$$\begin{align}
\log(3.6^{3.6})
&=3.6\log(3.6)=7.2(\log2+\log3)-3.6\\
&\approx7.2\cdot0.78-3.6\\
&=0.001((75-3)(75+3))-3.6\\&=0.001(75^2-9)-3.6\\
&=0.001(5625-9)-3.6\\
&=5.616-3.6=2.016\\
&\approx2
\end{align}$$

Note the "trick" $(a5)^2=(a(a+1))25$ for squaring $75$ (i.e., $56=7\cdot8$).

Remark: $\log2\approx0.3$ comes from $2^{10}=1024\approx10^3$. The estimate for $\log3$ can be obtained with a bit a rounding from $3^4\approx80$.

Comment: How do you get the $3.6\log(3.6)=7.2(\log2+\log3)-3.6$ ?

Comment: @Arthurim, $\log(3.6)=\log36-\log10=2\log6-1=2(\log2+\log3)-1$

Comment: Just, how do you get to first estimate 3.6? We know that x is between 3 and 5, but unless you knoiw the answer you have to go by trial and error right?

Comment: @Arthurim, I started with the obvious bounds $3\lt x\lt4$, as in gimusi's answer, then knew that $\log3.6$ would be easy to estimate from easy estimates of $\log2$ and $\log3$.  What's missing, of course, is any estimate of how close $3.6$ is to the actual answer.  That would require a good deal more work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

$3^3=27$

$4^4=256$

thus $3<x<4$.

Then you can try with $3.5^{3.5}$ and so on.

Comment: But already calculating $3.5^{3.5}$ in your head (or even on paper) is something only a few people can do today :P

Comment: Yes ok but at least you can get a good approximation!

Comment: You can compute $(7/2)^7$ and compare to $100^2$, @M.Winter So is $7^7>1,280,000$?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to approximate the final solution using rational numbers $p/q$. For this you try to find $p$ and $q$ so that

$$\left(\frac pq\right)^{p/q}\approx100\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad p^p\approx 100^q\cdot q^p.$$

With some time and patience, the latter form can be computed on paper. What makes an approximation *good*? Probably when you have that the quotient of $p^p$ and $100^q\cdot q^p$ is near one.

---

**An algorithm**

A good starting point (as seen in @gimusi's answer) would be $p=7$ and $q=2$. You would find that $823543=7^7 < 100^2\cdot 2^7=1280000$. Now you can do the following:

- If $p^p < 100^q\cdot q^p$ (as in this example), then replace $p\mapsto 3p$ and $q\mapsto2q$.
- If $p^p > 100^q\cdot q^p$, then only replace $q\mapsto2q$.

This is basically binary bisection. So according to above, the next approximation to check would be $p=21$ and $q=8$. And you do this again and again until the result is good enough for you. The exact result is irrational, so you cannot hope to find it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a sequence of approximations. Suppose you want to approximate this with rational numbers, so let $x=\frac{a}{b}$.

$$
(\frac{a}{b})^{\frac{a}{b}}=100
$$

Rearranging this gives $(100b)^b=a^a$. Now let $b=1,2,3\ldots$ and find a suitable $a$ that bounds the answer above or below. For example if $b=1$:

$$
27=3^3<100=(100\cdot1)^1<4^4=256,
$$

$b=2$:
$$
3125=5^5< 40,000=(100\cdot 2)^2 <6^6=46656,
$$

and $b=3$:

$$
16,777,216=8^8< 27,000,000=(100\cdot 3)^3 <9^9=387,420,489,
$$

one can obtain an upper and lower sequence of rational approximations:

$$
3,\frac{5}{2},\frac{8}{3}\ldots,\\
4,\frac{6}{2},\frac{9}{3}\ldots\\
$$

although this approach doesn't appear to converge terribly quickly.